# How many $2$-Sylow subgroups does $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ have?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> How many $2$-Sylow subgroups does $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ have?

I wanted to know if my proof is correct -

Since $|SL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)|=24$, we can see that $n_2|3$, and therefore $n_2=1,3$.

Assuming that $n_2=3$, we get that the are $3*8$ elements of order $2$, meaning the whole group.

It can't be, as $3|24=|(SL_2\mathbb{F}_3)|$, and by the first Sylow theorem there should be a subgroup of order $3$.

Therefore, $n_2=1$, and there is only one $2$-Sylow subgroup.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: No, you only get $3*(8-1) +1 = 22$ elements of order dividing $8$ from the Sylow subgroups. But that's still enough : can you find $4$ elements of order $3$ ?

Comment: @Max why do I need to look for $4$ elements of order $3$?

Comment: How do you know that the potential $3$ sylow-2 subgroups don't intersect?

Comment: The proof must be wrong because you have made no use at all of the fact that $G = {\rm SL}_2(3)$. You have only used the fact that $|G|=24$. But there are groups of order $24$ such as $S_4$ that really do have $n_2=3$.

Comment: @Derek Holt Could you give me a hint then?

Comment: The upper and lower unitriangular matrices are distinct subgroups of order $3$, so $n_3>1$, so $n_3=4$. This gives $8$ elements of order $3$. Multiply those by $-I_2$ and you get $8$ elements of order $6$. That leaves $8$ elements that have to form a unique Sylow $2$-subgroup.

Comment: @Derek Holt Why are those matrices of order $3$? And why by multiplying by $-I_2$ we get elements of order $6$?

Comment: Why not write down one of these matrices $a$ and calculate $a^3$?

Comment: @Derek Holt Thank you, I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in the comments, you need to try something else.  Here's one sketch of a possibility for that something else:

Use the fact that $SL(2,3)$ has a center $Z$ of order $2$ and $SL(2,3)/Z\cong A_4$.  Since $A_4$ has only four $2$-elements, $SL(2,3)$ can only have eight, so $n_2=1$.  Note that you can also use this isomorphism to show that $n_3=4$.

And if you don't already know that $SL(2,3)$ mod its center yields $A_4$, go ahead and try to prove it.  You'll end up understanding the structure of $SL(2,3)$ a lot better.  (The main other thing to know about $SL(2,3)$ is that its $2$-Sylow is quaternion--try showing that, too.)

Hint on showing $SL(2,3)/Z\cong A_4$: Remember that $SL(2,3)/Z\cong PSL(2,3)$ which acts faithfully on the projective line over $\Bbb{F}_3$.  That line has four points, so $PSL(2,3)$ must be isomorphic to an order $12$ subgroup of $S_4$.  How many candidates are there? :)